# ¿Cómo acceder a las variables de un array en PHP?

Tags: php

Necesito obtener los id (iduser e idselect) de el siguiente array para luego almacenarlos en base de datos.
Codigo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($actualizaciones); $i++) {

print_r( $actualizaciones[$i]);
echo "<br>";

}
```

Esto es lo que me trae al recorrer el array:

```
Array ( [iduser] => 1 [idselect] => 2 ) 
Array ( [iduser] => 2 [idselect] => 3 )
```

Comment: Hola @Diego la estructura del **array** original es la que estas representado o estas trabajando un **array** asociativo.  En caso que sea así puedes colocar el **array** original.

Comment: Hola, antes no era un array si no un listado de objetos. Al convertirlo en un array la estructura quedo asi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu array es un array con el modelo clave-valor, es decir, cada valor está asociado a una clave (un nombre) dentro del array.

Por lo tanto, cuando vayas recorriendo cada uno de los dos arrays lo que tienes que hacer es acceder a la clave de dichos valores.

Ejemplo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($actualizaciones); $i++) {
   print_r( $actualizaciones[$i]["iduser"]);
   print_r( $actualizaciones[$i]["idselect"]);
   echo "<br>";
}
```

**Nota:** Como en este caso solo vas a imprimir valores y no arrays, no necesitarías el uso de `print_r` (que te muestra el tipo de dato que contiene la variable que estás mostrando), si no que podrías utilizar la sentencia `echo`.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que $actualizaciones es un array que contiene 2 array.

Comment: @DiegoLopez Sí, por eso al realizar el bucle `for` vas a recorrer cada uno de los arrays. En tu caso tu array `$actualizaciones` es un array bidimensional (un array de arrays). Por lo tanto, con el índice `$i` vas indicando a que array estás haciendo referencia y con el segundo índice (`iduser` e `idselect`) es donde indicas que valores quieres obtener de cada array.

Comment: Me ha funcionado muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si tu array es así:

```
$arrActualizaciones=array(
                           array("iduser"=>1, "idselect"=>2),
                           array("iduser"=>2, "idselect"=>3)
                         );

print_r($arrActualizaciones);
```

El `print_r` (únicamente para depurar y ver cómo se construye el array), se ve así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iduser] => 1
            [idselect] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iduser] => 2
            [idselect] => 3
        )

)
```

---

Y para leerlo, que es lo que te interesa:

```
foreach ($arrActualizaciones as $row)
{
    $intUser= $row["iduser"];
    $intSelect= $row["idselect"];

    echo  "user: ".$intUser.PHP_EOL;   
    echo  "select: ".$intSelect.PHP_EOL;   
    echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

}
```

**Output**

```
user: 1
select: 2


user: 2
select: 3
```

Puedes guardar los datos en variables: `$intUser= $row["iduser"];` o usarlos directamente.

Comment: Hola, me sale lo siguiente "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\proyectos\formulario\actualizar.php on line 8"

Comment: Quizá es por el nombre, yo lo he llamado `$arrActualizaciones`, es mi convención de nombres. Verifica que las variables corresponden.

Comment: @DiegoLopez Date cuenta de que A. Cedano ha usado el nombre `$arrActualizaciones`. En tu caso lo deberías de cambiar por `$actualizaciones`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!